# Does energy always flow following an entropy gradient?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

Is it possible to write down a certain kind of 'flow' or 'diffusion equation' where the direction energy flows always follows an entropy gradient?

Comment: Yes. The Euler equations do that, extensively used in gas/flow dynamics modelling. There, the third equation, the energy equation is equivalent to $d_t S = Q$, where Q will in general be some flux-divergence term.

Comment: In reversible adiabatic process work flows between the surroundings and the system under zero entropy gradient. In this sense the answer to your question is No.

Comment: What is your definition of the term "energy flow?"

Comment: @ChetMiller We can assume that energy "flow" means energy transfer.

Comment: What is your definition of the term energy transfer?

Comment: In thermal conductivity, entropy flow, and thus thermal energy flow, follows *temperature gradient*.

Comment: Energy flows down [intensive-parameter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intensive_and_extensive_properties) gradients to generate entropy. See, for example, Baluffi et al.’s *Kinetics of Materials* for entropy-production equations.